# preg_replace json string match same character beginning/end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok so what I have is a JSON string which can contain 1 or many elements below I've put an example of the sting but this is only an example the real string is much more complicated. This one highlight's the issue's I'm having.

```
{"elements":[{"id":2,"string":"something","string2":"","string3":"no html  here","integer":2,"array":{"options":[{"id":1,"value":"data"},{"id":2,"value":"more data"}]},"string4":"text with <a href=\"http:\/\/www.example.com\">html<\/a>","string5":"naughty <a href=\"http:\/\/www.example.com\">link<\/a>"},{"id":2,"string":"something","string2":"","string3":"no html here","integer":2,"array":{"options":[{"id":1,"value":"data"},{"id":2,"value":"more data"}]},"string4":"text with <a href=\"http:\/\/www.example.com\">html<\/a>","string5":"naughty <a href=\"http:\/\/www.example.com\">link<\/a>"}]}
```

What I'm trying to do is match all of the Strings (data-type not the name) in the JSON data and then depending on whether it's allowed HTML or not (using a blacklist) striping out the HTML. I'm no regex expert so I can't work out what's going wrong.

Here is my regex:-

```
([{,]"(?!(elements|string3|string4)":)(.*?)":)(?!,")"(.*?)",
```

I'm having two issue's with it:-

1. It is matching elements with both integer's and array's by simply jumping to the " found within the next string. I expected the match to fail and move on
2. I can't get it to handle the \" in the url so I need the , on the end of the regex but this then stop's the next string matching I tried \G but this seemed to have no affect I have a feeling it starts after the , in the previous match. I also tried a number of solutions that were suppose to allow for escaped text but these all failed to work in my case.

The thought was that this would be quicker than converting the JSON string into an object and then traversing the array of hundreds of elements to remove the HTML if that's quicker then I'll just do that it'll be a whole lot easier.

Comment: Just a question: Have you ever heard about **[json_decode()](http://php.net/json-decode)** ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't work on the json directly, decode it using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Then cleanup your HTML using [`HTMLPurifier`](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which does a great job at cleaning HTML code.

Then encode your data to json again using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 1):

## Description

There were several problems with your expression like the use of `.*?` will continue to capture all characters until the next required character is matched. I replaced this with `[^"]*?` which will match all non quotes, this forces the capture to stop consuming characters which are outside the quoted group.

I also made a capture group for the open quotes `(["])` although probably overkill this allows you to simply add a single quote to the character class. Then I refer back to this captured group later to ensure the correct corresponding close quote is also matched. This way if the open quote is not required in your input string then you can simply insert a question mark `(["])?` and the close quote will automatically be found that matches the open quote.

I also moved the `[{,]` to outside the capture group

This is my cleaned up version of the regex

`[{,]((")(?!(elements|string3|string4)\2:)([^"]*?)\2:)(")([^"]*?)\5(?=,)`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/[{,]((")(?!(elements|string3|string4)\2:)([^"]*?)\2:)(")([^"]*?)\5(?=,)/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
 
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,"string0":"something0"
            [1] => ,"string1":""
            [2] => ,"string":"something"
            [3] => ,"string5":""
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "string0":
            [1] => "string1":
            [2] => "string":
            [3] => "string5":
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
            [2] => "
            [3] => "
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => string0
            [1] => string1
            [2] => string
            [3] => string5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
            [2] => "
            [3] => "
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => something0
            [1] => 
            [2] => something
            [3] => 
        )

)
```